# Why the result of the function invoked twice is different?

Tags: javascript, scope

```
function makeCounter() {
    var i = 0;
    return function() {
        console.log( ++i );
    };
}

var counter = makeCounter();
counter(); // logs: 1
counter(); // logs: 2
```

why the result of counter() invoked the second time is '2' but not '1'?

I try to find out its executing processes, so I rewrite **makeCounter()**:

```
function makeCounter() {
    var i = 0;
    console.log('outer');
    return function() {
        console.log('inner');
        console.log( ++i );
    };
}

var counter = makeCounter();
counter();
counter();
```

and result is:

```
outer
inner
1
inner
2
```

Can I think that:
**i** is the argument of function **counter()**, the first **counter()** executed, **i** changes to '1'. So the second **counter()** executed, **i** is '2'.

Comment: It is called as closure variable

Comment: All calls of `counter` will refer to the same instance of `i` and when that value is updated in `counter` it will updated the shared instance value

Comment: Thank you~ I  can understand what closure is, but the variable `i` in this example puzzles me. Need more learning and training. thank you~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is an effect of what is called a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FClosures) in JavaScript. To fully understand it, I would recommend you have a look at [How do JavaScript closures work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) from where the following quote is taken:

> In JavaScript, if you declare a function within another function, then the local variables can remain accessible after returning from the function you called.

In your case, an anonymous function is declared within the `makeCounter` function, creating a closure (it will "remember" all the local variables at that point). The anonymous function will therefore still be able to access the variable `i` even after `makeCounter` has exited. As a result, each call to the anonymous function will increment the very same `i` variable.

```
function makeCounter() {
    var i = 0;
    return function() {
        console.log( ++i ); // Will always use the same variable "i"
    };
}

var counter = makeCounter();
counter(); // logs: 1
counter(); // logs: 2
```